# Can I use TestNG DataProvider in Spring Context i.e. in my Test Code which runswith SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: java, spring, junit4, testng-dataprovider

I am doing some `Junit` testing in `Spring` and in my Test Class I have to use some test data.

I searched google and there are many ways like - `Parameterized` Class, TestNG `Data` Providers, `[junit-dataprovider][1]` etc.

I though to try TestNG data Provider and created a simple class for my test data as below:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
public class TestNgDataProvider extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestNgDataProvider.class);

    @DataProvider(name = "invoices")
    public static Object[][] dataProviderMethod() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {"201628JP00006097", "201628JP00006098"},
        };
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "invoices")
    public void testParameterMethod(String invoiceId1, String invoiceId2) {
        LOGGER.info("Start test");
        LOGGER.info("Test data is: {}, {}", invoiceId1, invoiceId2);

    }
}
```

However now when I try to use this provider in my Test Class I get an `exception` saying:
**java.lang.Exception**: No runnable methods

My Test Class is using runWith `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`. Anybody knows how to resolve this issue.

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(TestConfiguration.class)
public class TestLax extends LaxBaseTest {
  @Test (dataProvider="invoices", dataProviderClass=TestNgDataProvider.class)
    public void testLarsTamara(String invoiceId1, String invoiceId2) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Test data is: {}, {}", invoiceId1, invoiceId2);

        File file = larsRemote.runLars();
        readAndVerifyLarsFile(file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can't !

JUnit is not able to run TestNG tests or features. 
But at the opposite, TestNG is able to run junit tests.

Just run your tests with the testng way and it should work.